# Implementation of std::vector<T>::iterator::operator[]

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator

For this code:

```
  std::vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  std::cout << (vec.begin() + 4)[2] << " \n"; // prints out 6
  std::cout << (vec.begin() + 4)[-1] << "\n"; // prints out 3
```

It output 6 and 3 as expected.

I checked the cppreference, but couldn't find the definition of `std::vector::iterator::operator[]`, so I am wondering if is this actually defined behavior.

I checked the header file `vector` and follows it to `bits/stl_vector.h` and the iterator definition at `bits/stl_iterator.h`. My compiler version is `g++-11 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 11.1.0`

It is clear that in `bits/stl_iterator.h` an iterator's element (`_M_current`) is a `T*` (see the iterator's typedef in `bits/stl_vector.h`). So negative index as pointer arithmetic makes sense. But is it defined, that the type `iterator` must imitate a `T*`, such that all arithmetic operations of a random access iterator must be compatible with a pointer?

Also, is `T*::operator[]` defined in C++? Where can I find its definition?

Comment: The built-in subscript expression `E1[E2]` is exactly identical to the expression `*(E1 + E2)`

Comment: @user17732522 I think the user is trying to answer my last problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` is a [*Cpp17RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), where for an iterator `a`, [`a[n]` works as `*(a + n)`](https://eel.is/c++draft/random.access.iterators#tab:randomaccessiterator-row-8).

And "`T*::operator[]`" is called the "built-in subscript operator" which, when selected, means `pointer[index]` is identical to `*((pointer) + (index))`. It is defined [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#2), satisfying the requirement for *Cpp17RandomAccessIterator* immediately.

For the purposes of overload resolution, it has the signature [`T& operator[](T*, std::ptrdiff_t)`](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#13) (Though the index isn't actually converted to `std::ptrdiff_t`). This is a built-in declaration, so will be somewhere in the compiler itself.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation （I can only `accept` but not upvote it because I don't have reputation).